# Vue router and Vite Base url conflict

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vite, cdn

I use Vue Router to develop my single page application and use Vite to package my project. I want to deploy all static files (such as `index.js` and `index.css`) under another CDN domain name `cdn.example.com`, so I used Vite Base command to build the code.

```
vite build --base http://cdn.example.com/
```

The main site of my website is `http://example.com`, when I visit it, the static files will automatically access `cdn.example.com`, and the website can be opened normally. But the route of the website has become `http://example.com/http://cdn.example.com/`, and the route of Vue router is also invalid (that is, when I visit `http://example.com/about`, it displays a 404). This confuses me, how should I fix this?

Comment: You can try providing a `base` in [createWebHistory](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#Functions-createWebHistory)